# Camera does not finish with clicking onBackPressed

Tags: java, android

I want to call camera intent in on Start Method and it works fine, but when i click on back button it does not go back from camera because Uri is empty. I want to go to previous Activity with clicking back button.

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
  if (uri==null){
      Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
   }
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: Why do you have the code in `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: you can ignore that sir

Comment: I think you need `onActivityResult` to listen to backPressed on Camera intent. Not the parent Activity which `startActivityForResult`.

Comment: i think there is no need to add the method onBackPressed just remove it

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class with a static boolean variable like below,

```
public class HelperUtil
    {
        public static boolean isCameraActivityBackPressed;
    }
```

And change your code little bit,

```
    @Override
        protected void onStart()
        {
            super.onStart();
            if (uri == null)
            {
                if (HelperUtil.isCameraActivityBackPressed)
                {
                    // this block will execute when ActivityCamera back is pressed and uri is null

                    startActivity(new Intent(this, ReplaceWithYourActivity.class));

                } else
                {
                    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            super.onBackPressed();

            HelperUtil.isCameraActivityBackPressed = true;

            Toast.makeText(ActivityCamera.this, "onbackpressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityCamera.class));
            finish();
        }
```

Comment: camera is system app that's why our backpressed does not work here.. do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: If you want to go to previous Activity with clicking back button. You need to change the line startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityCamera.class)); to startActivity(new Intent(this, .PreviousActivity.class));

Comment: ActivityCamera is the name of my Activity

Comment: If you want to go to previous Activity(let's say ActivityTest) with clicking back button (in ActivityCamera). then, replace line startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityCamera.class)); to startActivity(new Intent(ActivityCamera.this, ActivityTest.class));